# IAR Workbench Simulator on a STM32G0 get stuck at wait till PLL is ready

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, iar

I have an example code that calls SystemClock_Config() in the main function.

When i launch the simulation from IAR Workbench the main function get stuck in the above call particularly when it does

```
/* Wait till PLL is ready */
while (READ_BIT(RCC->CR, RCC_CR_PLLRDY) == 0U)
{
    if ((HAL_GetTick() - tickstart) > PLL_TIMEOUT_VALUE)
    {
         return HAL_TIMEOUT;
    }
}
```

I just recently started playing around with this tool.
I thought that the simulator was supposed to take care of this given there is no "PLL" since i don't have an HW.

Answer (score 3):

It is an ARM I instruction set simulator, it does not simulate peripheral hardware, including the PLL.

You could manually set `RCC_CR_PLLRDY` or skip the loop by setting the program counter to a point after the loop, or you could write a debugger script attached to a breakpoint that sets `RCC_CR_PLLRDY` and continues (if IAR had that capability).

You will no doubt however encounter similar issues with any hardware peripherals,on or off chip.

An alternative is to use conditional compilation for a `SIMULATION` build that skips or stubs the hardware accesses in your code.

Comment: I feel so down knowning they can't even take care of this. If i have to go with your solution it means that i can't even focus on code development but simulator integration :& It basically mean it is no different than running my code on a totally different target platform since it won't try to reproduce a specific hw behaviour

Comment: It is an ARM development tool, not specifically STM32, whilst the PLL in this case is STM32 specific.  You are asking a lot for IAR to accurately simulate the behaviour of every possible ARM MCU available.  I agree that the simulator is of very limited use.  You may do better to test in an inexpensive dev or evaluation board.  They are so cheap there is hardly any need to attempt to simulate. https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-g031k8.html. For code that is not hardware dependent (such as algorithms), it is often more productive to prototype in a Desktop PC.

Comment: ... a clear separation between device layer and application layer past dividends here.